# Finding a specific RGB value from XA, YA to XB, YB

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Lets say I was to draw an imaginary box on the screen.  Within that box, I need to find a specific RGB value and return it's pixel location.  I was originally multi-threading, using `pyautogui` to move the mouse and taking the color value from under the cursor, but it's not reliable and I'm sure there is an easier way.  Unfortunately I do not work with image processing at all, so I turn to you guys for help.  Can I use PIL, or other packages, to find a specific RGB value within a given pixel range, and return the pixel value(s)?  If so, how?

Comment: Let's say the image is stored in a variable named `image`. And your pixel values are R = 50, G = 60, and B = 80. Your pixel value will be `image[np.where((image[...,0]==R) & (image[...,1]==G) & (image[...,2]==B))]`
In case you have to check in a range, you get the idea just put a few more comparisons in `np.where` using `>` or `<`.

Comment: @SayandipDutta If I have to load an image, ideally it would be a screen capture, not an image file.  What is np?  numpy?

Comment: I think you'd get a better answer if you gave a sample image and colour to detect. Also if you indicated whether you are having difficulties drawing your imaginary box - although I'm not sure if we'll be able to see an imaginary one, or if finding the colour is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do. You can read your image using `PIL` or `OpenCV` (I prefer `OpenCV`) using:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('path_to_image')
```

This will return you with a numpy array of the shape (height, width, channels). Since its a colored image it will have 3 channels, in `opencv` the BGR color scheme is followed.

So to find the pixels with specified values, use can use `where` function of numpy as suggested in the comments

```
red,green,blue = 10,20,30
pixels = np.where((img[...,0]==blue) & (img[...,1]==green) & (img[...,2]==red))
```

`pixels` will be the array containing the indexes of the pixels in the image.

Comment: It would be preferred to take a screen capture or something.  There are no image files ideally.  It doesn't look like you read within a specific pixel range (e.g. from x600 y200 to x1200 y600)?  What are you defining `pixels` as?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with `PIL` is to use the [`ImageGrab`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html) module to get the region that you want to search.

Then you can use the `load()` method, to load all pixels of that region and find all these pixels that have a specific RGB value.

Below is the code demostrating the above suggestion:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

x_start = 0
y_start = 0
width = 400
height = 400

bbox = (x_start,y_start,width,height)
rgb = (0,0,0)

image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)

pixels = image.load()
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        if pixels[x,y] == rgb:
            print("{} {}".format(x,y))
```